# Removing big spaces below figures or tables - acmart document class

Tags: vertical-spacing, acmart

My document uses the following template:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm]{acmart}
```

Where `acmart.cls` can be found from [the ACM website (LaTeX (Version 1.83))](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).

The spaces below figures or tables are inconsistent:

[image: Big red brackets indicate the space]

Because my document needs to reduce its number of pages, I have to make all such vertical spaces be consistently minimal (i.e. a single space). How can I enforce all such inconsistent spacing to always use only a single space? This includes not only for tables or figures, but also for sections and subsections.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Spaces is not inconsistent. They are determined by used `\documentclass` .  If you not liked some of them, insert there negative vertical space, for example `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`. But better (an harder) approach is reformulate your articles that it become shorter.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Yes, using \vspace will be a way to fix it. But I just wonder if there is a way to automatically do it all at once for the entire document..

Comment: you haven't provided any usable example but the space between top floats and the text body is `\textfloatsep`  so you should be able to set that to whatever you like

Comment: Thanks very much, this works out for me: ```\setlength\textfloatsep{\baselineskip}```